# how to change svn default repository path in linux fedora 20?

Tags: linux, fedora

I have latest Fedora20 and SVN. When `svnserve.service` starts, the default repository path, `/var/svn`, is passed in. But I don't want to put my repository there. I want put in there: `/home/svn`. I can use `svnadmin` to create repository there. if the default path, `/var/svn`, doesn't exist, the `svnserve.service` wouldn't start.

My question is how can I change that default parameter, passed in to the `svnserve.service`, to point to my new repository location?

if `/var/svn` is there:

```
$systemctl status svnserve.service
svnserve.service - Subversion protocol daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/svnserve.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2014-09-04 10:25:12 EDT; 7h ago
 Main PID: 1128 (svnserve)
   CGroup: /system.slice/svnserve.service
           └─1128 /usr/bin/svnserve --daemon --pid-file=/run/svnserve/svnserve.pid -r /var/svn
```

above shows the `/var/svn` is passed as parameter at the last line. where I can modify that?

I want to use `systemctl` to make svn running automatically after each reboot.